# Hide and show two modals, scroll does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problems with the modal bootstrap 3.3.7

I have 2 modes, one being bigger than the other. When I open the larger modal by a button within the smaller modal, the scroll does not work in the larger modal.

```
$('#btnOpenModalLarger').click(function(){
     $('#modalSmall').modal('hide');
     $('#modalLarger').modal('show');
});
```

[image]

[image]

> Ps: In bootstrap 3.2.x it works normally, in version 3.3.7 it does not ;(

Comment: I have the same logic on my site but I don't use modal hide, I simply open a new modal in button click. The other modal disappears by itself. If that does not work you could also try to make a fadeToggle on click like "Show more Options" button and than the modal expends itself. Both should work.

Comment: Please create a fiddle so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the first modal get closed '.modal-open' class get removed from body. That's why you cannot see the scroll bar.

So you need to add '.modal-open' class once the second model event fires using shown.bs.modal method. Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32z10o51/2/)** (full screen view [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/32z10o51/2/embedded/result/)

```
$('#btnOpenModalLarger').click(function() {
  $('#modalSmall').modal('hide');
  $('#modalLarger').modal('show');
});

$('#modalLarger').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('body').addClass('modal-open');
})
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks